# iOS http authentication to windows using Transport WebHttpSecurityMode

Tags: ios, authentication

I am trying get an iPad app to authenticate to Windows based application that uses WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport mode. I am assuming that I need specific fields in the http header to be filled out correctly to make this happen.

I am using NSURLConnections and then sending a request using sendSynchronousRequest. I am sending a rest request through the connection and receiving a (401) unauthorized. With a windows client I can use the same credentials and gain access.

I am setting the following fields in the http header
Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Content-Type, Connection, Date, Basic, Authization.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.